Kubean Failed ! error in making cluster using daocloud
I'm trying to set up a cluster using DaoCloud, but I've been facing issues that I can't seem to resolve. I've attached a screenshot of the error message I'm encountering: Screenshot.
Problem Description:
The installation fails at step 6 with a message indicating it couldn't obtain kube.conf from the Cluster CRD my-cluster.
The error message also suggests checking above error messages and mentions that the shell execution error status is 3.

